# Can WireGuard be forced to route through a specific peer if it is locally available?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

This is more of a general "can this be done" question, so while I am happy for every piece of actual configuration that helps to set this up, my main intention is to understand if this was feasible in the first place.

Consider a scenario, where laptops are used in multiple locations. While they are connected to an office network on a regular basis, it is also common practise for team members to work from home office, having only an internet connection (for this we want to ignore any other VPN solution).

Now consider a resource in a public cloud that should be reachable from the laptops. While it can be reached over the public internet, the better choice is to rely on an existing MPLS connection from the office network.

Can there be a WireGuard setup that is still easy to use (for the end users using the laptops) and routes VPN traffic targeting the cloud systems over MPLS whenever the laptop has a network connection.

The laptops will use a wireless network in the office as well as in home offices, and we can't guarantee the office network IPv4 range is unique and won't collide with ranges defined by the private routers at home.

Please note that this is of course a simplified setup. The main question here is if we can make use of the MPLS connection when a computer is in a certain network and fall back to an internet connection otherwise. From a technical point of view, it should route packages targeting the cloud through the office server peer if and only if it is reachable via a private ip address.

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary for the laptops to tunnel WireGuard directly to the cloud server instead of tunneling to your office server? (i.e. always using your MPLS link to cloud regardless of the user's location)?

Comment: @user1686 no, they don't need to directly connect through the cloud server. but routing through the office server would be very inefficient if the laptop is not in the office, so a connection `Internet -> Cloud Server` would be preferred if outside of the office

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to have the *office network* route your cloud server's public IP address range through the private MPLS link (i.e. an exception to the default route through public WAN).

This would be completely transparent to users, and would work with any kind of traffic, not only WireGuard tunnels. (With something like OSPF or BGP in place, it would also allow for transparent failover to the public Internet link in case the MPLS link ever goes down.)